# finite dimensional marginal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the following theorem:

"The distribution of a stochastic process is uniquely determined by the family of all its finite-dimensional marginal distribution (and vice versa)"

I am not very familiar with this definition of fdmd which is given as follows:

"For each set of indices $J=\{t_1,...,t_n\}\subset [0,\infty)$ with $t_1<...<t_n$, we can view 
$$\mu^{(J)}:=\mathbb{P}\circ(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n})^{-1}$$ as the distribution of the vector $X_{(J)}:=(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n})$ under $\mathbb{P}$, as a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{\mid J\mid}=\mathbb{R}^n$. We call this the finite-dimensional marginal distribution (fdmd) of $X$ for the coordinates in $J$".

So if I am right then the theorem would consider all possible vectors $X$ (constructed choosing all possible finite set $J$) with all possible number of components and states that the distribution of a stochastic process is so determined (uniquely) by the distributions of all these possible vector. I am a bit confused since I usually from the distribution of single random variables we can't recover the one of the vector. Is this theorem stating when this actually happens? Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Note that $n$ is allowed to be *any* positive integer. Applying it on a vector $(X,Y)$ it says that the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is determined by the distributions of $X$, $Y$ **and** $(X,Y)$. Well, that is correct.

Comment: okay but in your case $J$ is still finite. In my definition I have uncountable many $X$'s in my process and each time a fdmd is the distribution of finite many of them.

Comment: What I meant to say (nothing less, nothing more) was that this theorem is not inconsistent with the statement that in general the distribution of a vector cannot be recovered from the distribution its single random variables.